# Copy and Pasting using Macros in excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, macros

I'm trying to Copy from a row of text in the "lookup sheet" column and paste into row two starting at CCX2.
For example I need to copy 2856FRGM and paste into 12 cells (CCX2 - CDI2), then followed by 2856GRPM and paste into the next 12 cells and so on.

I have approximately 3600 unique part numbers to do this with.

[image]

So far this is the Macro I have but it's pasting the first part number full length of the excel instead of 12 rows per part number.
Only starting a new part number in the row below.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, only started with Macros today so I don't really know what I'm doing lol

Comment: Do you want to copy `2856FRGM` for example 12 times in rows or columns? (CCX2-CDI2 are columns)

Comment: I want to copy 2856FRGM from D10 and paste it horizontally 12 times from CCX2 to CDI2.

Comment: If you have 3600 unique part * 12 do you know how many columns?

Comment: 3510 unique part numbers that I want to paste each *12 horizontally.  Each part number is it's own column so after I paste there would be 42120 columns

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, can you post your code, and format with `{}`?

Answer (score 0):

Sub paste()

( "H4:H5" ). Select Selection.Copy Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _ := False, Transpose:= False Range( "H8" ). Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Selection.Copy Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks := False, Transpose:= False Range
( "H10" ). Select

Application.CutCopyMode =
False

Selection.Copy Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _ := False, Transpose:= False Range
( "H13:H16" ). Select

Application.CutCopyMode =
False 
Selection.Copy Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks := False, Transpose:= False

End Sub

NB. It's sample code adjust your cell address as you need.